AWS CDK tutorial generates a broken template?
I'm working through the AWS Cloud Development Kit (CDK) tutorial at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/hello_world.html. Working in CloudShell, I got through step 7 with no trouble; step 6 produced the following template.
Resources:
  HelloWorldFunctionServiceRole8E0BD458:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          - Action: sts:AssumeRole
            Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service: lambda.amazonaws.com
        Version: "2012-10-17"
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - Fn::Join:
            - ""
            - - "arn:"
              - Ref: AWS::Partition
              - :iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole
    Metadata:
      aws:cdk:path: HelloCdkStack/HelloWorldFunction/ServiceRole/Resource
  HelloWorldFunctionB2AB6E79:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
    Properties:
      Code:
        ZipFile: "

          \        exports.handler = async function(event) {

          \          return {

          \            statusCode: 200,

          \            body: JSON.stringify('Hello World!'),

          \          };

          \        };

          \      "
      Handler: index.handler
      Role:
        Fn::GetAtt:
          - HelloWorldFunctionServiceRole8E0BD458
          - Arn
      Runtime: nodejs20.x
    DependsOn:
      - HelloWorldFunctionServiceRole8E0BD458
    Metadata:
      aws:cdk:path: HelloCdkStack/HelloWorldFunction/Resource
  HelloWorldFunctionFunctionUrl4150BDAD:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Url
    Properties:
      AuthType: NONE
      TargetFunctionArn:
        Fn::GetAtt:
          - HelloWorldFunctionB2AB6E79
          - Arn
    Metadata:
      aws:cdk:path: HelloCdkStack/HelloWorldFunction/FunctionUrl/Resource
  HelloWorldFunctioninvokefunctionurlA2CB1A84:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
    Properties:
      Action: lambda:InvokeFunctionUrl
      FunctionName:
        Fn::GetAtt:
          - HelloWorldFunctionB2AB6E79
          - Arn
      FunctionUrlAuthType: NONE
      Principal: "*"
    Metadata:
      aws:cdk:path: HelloCdkStack/HelloWorldFunction/invoke-function-url
  CDKMetadata:
    Type: AWS::CDK::Metadata
    Properties:
      Analytics: v2:deflate64:H4sIAAAAAAAA/02MyQrCMBRFv6X75NkWEfcFt0rFtaRJhNdmkAy6CPl3mzjg6lzOgdtDt91B27Cnp1wsVOEE6RwYX8iqrkkxPQkG6RAND2gNGW7mt7/j4lTxH5yk0+j96jNBpiGNVskSCnMmo/Q2Ol7VMYZ7DDX+2cEagaEeGCskzH7z6PbQt9A3s0ekLpqAWsL45gvvKoubxQAAAA==
    Metadata:
      aws:cdk:path: HelloCdkStack/CDKMetadata/Default
    Condition: CDKMetadataAvailable
Outputs:
  myFunctionUrlOutput:
    Value:
      Fn::GetAtt:
        - HelloWorldFunctionFunctionUrl4150BDAD
        - FunctionUrl
Conditions:
  CDKMetadataAvailable:
    Fn::Or:
      - Fn::Or:
          - Fn::Equals:
              - Ref: AWS::Region
              - af-south-1
          - Fn::Equals:
              - Ref: AWS::Region
              - ap-east-1
          - Fn::Equals:
              - Ref: AWS::Region
              - ap-northeast-1
          - Fn::Equals:
              - Ref: AWS::Region
              - ap-northeast-2
          - Fn::Equals:
              - Ref: AWS::Region
              - ap-south-1
          - Fn::Equals:
              - Ref: AWS::Region
              - ap-southeast-1
          - Fn::Equals:
              - Ref: AWS::Region
              - ap-southeast-2
          - Fn::Equals:
              - Ref: AWS::Region
              - ca-central-1
          - Fn::Equals:
              - Ref: AWS::Region
              - cn-north-1
          - Fn::Equals:
              - Ref: AWS::Region
              - cn-northwest-1
      - Fn::Or:
          - Fn::Equals:
              - Ref: AWS::Region
              - eu-central-1
          - Fn::Equals:
              - Ref: AWS::Region
              - eu-north-1
          - Fn::Equals:
              - Ref: AWS::Region
              - eu-south-1
          - Fn::Equals:
              - Ref: AWS::Region
              - eu-west-1
          - Fn::Equals:
              - Ref: AWS::Region
              - eu-west-2
          - Fn::Equals:
              - Ref: AWS::Region
              - eu-west-3
          - Fn::Equals:
              - Ref: AWS::Region
              - il-central-1
          - Fn::Equals:
              - Ref: AWS::Region
              - me-central-1
          - Fn::Equals:
              - Ref: AWS::Region
              - me-south-1
          - Fn::Equals:
              - Ref: AWS::Region
              - sa-east-1
      - Fn::Or:
          - Fn::Equals:
              - Ref: AWS::Region
              - us-east-1
          - Fn::Equals:
              - Ref: AWS::Region
              - us-east-2
          - Fn::Equals:
              - Ref: AWS::Region
              - us-west-1
          - Fn::Equals:
              - Ref: AWS::Region
              - us-west-2
Parameters:
  BootstrapVersion:
    Type: AWS::SSM::Parameter::Value<String>
    Default: /cdk-bootstrap/hnb659fds/version
    Description: Version of the CDK Bootstrap resources in this environment, automatically retrieved from SSM Parameter Store. [cdk:skip]
Rules:
  CheckBootstrapVersion:
    Assertions:
      - Assert:
          Fn::Not:
            - Fn::Contains:
                - - "1"
                  - "2"
                  - "3"
                  - "4"
                  - "5"
                - Ref: BootstrapVersion
        AssertDescription: CDK bootstrap stack version 6 required. Please run 'cdk bootstrap' with a recent version of the CDK CLI.

But when I run step 8, executing cdk deploy, I get the following response:
 ❌  HelloCdkStack failed: Error [ValidationError]: Template format error: Unrecognized resource types: [AWS::Lambda::Url]
    at Request.extractError (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/index.js:401:46723)
    at Request.callListeners (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/index.js:401:91777)
    at Request.emit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/index.js:401:91225)
    at Request.emit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/index.js:401:199828)
    at Request.transition (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/index.js:401:193380)
    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/index.js:401:158252)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/index.js:401:158582
    at Request.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/index.js:401:193672)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/index.js:401:199903)
    at Request.callListeners (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/index.js:401:91945) {
  code: 'ValidationError',
  time: 2024-08-12T18:34:33.761Z,
  requestId: '0cc0f0d3-9940-495b-bf2a-f4578ef910f0',
  statusCode: 400,
  retryable: false,
  retryDelay: 261.7239740021147
}

 ❌ Deployment failed: Error [ValidationError]: Template format error: Unrecognized resource types: [AWS::Lambda::Url]
    at Request.extractError (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/index.js:401:46723)
    at Request.callListeners (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/index.js:401:91777)
    at Request.emit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/index.js:401:91225)
    at Request.emit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/index.js:401:199828)
    at Request.transition (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/index.js:401:193380)
    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/index.js:401:158252)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/index.js:401:158582
    at Request.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/index.js:401:193672)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/index.js:401:199903)
    at Request.callListeners (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/index.js:401:91945) {
  code: 'ValidationError',
  time: 2024-08-12T18:34:33.761Z,
  requestId: '0cc0f0d3-9940-495b-bf2a-f4578ef910f0',
  statusCode: 400,
  retryable: false,
  retryDelay: 261.7239740021147

So, CDK doesn't recognize the AWS::Lambda::Url resource type that CDK itself included in the template that it generated? I'm getting no clue from the error message as to what to do about this.

Deploying to an AWS region that doesn't support Lambda function URLs? See unsupported list of regions here.

Huh, it seems weird that such a feature would be missing from particular zones. But, no, this is a US zone, not on the unsupported list.

The error message you're seeing is not coming from CDK as far as I can tell. It's coming from the CloudFormation service. I say that because there is a requestId which suggests that the CDK client has actually made an API request to an AWS service (CloudFormation in this case). That suggests to me that it's not a CDK issue per se.

I guess you're right because I went directly to CloudFormation and created a stack using the same YAML and got the same complaint, "Template format error: Unrecognized resource types: [AWS::Lambda::Url]" Nice of AWS to include a limited-availability feature in a tutorial. I guess I can try to figure out how to swap in API Gateway instead.

It looks like they have a tutorial based on API Gateway: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/serverless_example.html. I'll check it out.

Or simply use a different region.

The error message that you are receiving is from CloudFormation, not from CDK. It indicates that Lambda function URLs are not supported in the AWS region that you are deploying to.
See Creating and managing Lambda function URLs:

Function URLs are not supported in the following regions: Asia Pacific (Hyderabad) (ap-south-2), Asia Pacific (Melbourne) (ap-southeast-4), Canada West (Calgary) (ca-west-1), Europe (Spain) (eu-south-2), Europe (Zurich) (eu-central-2), Israel (Tel Aviv) (il-central-1), and Middle East (UAE) (me-central-1).

If this relates to a demo or tutorial deployment, rather than a production system (which would require more thought), then I'd suggest using a nearby region that does support Lambda function URLs.

How do I  "use" a different region? I'm using a sandbox account that my employer set up for experimentation, and it's in a region.

Your employer may have restricted which region(s) you can use but see choosing a region or, when using the various CLIs, supply the --region option.

An AWS account is never "in a region".
